# UNION 3 Identical Tables and SUM 4 Columns

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables on my database that are identical in structure....

ID | Timestamp | Year | Month | Day | Hour | Water | Electric | Natural Gas | Solar Generation

Each row of data is identical accept for Water, Electric, Natural Gas and Solar Generation. Those four columns are random numbers. The data is produced by a PHP script that is fired by a cronjob each hour. Right now I have data that goes back to Jan 1 2018 to present, by hour. So there are just over 11,000 records in each table now. I have accomplished a few tasks with sql queries, but by no means an expert and I am having a bit of difficulty with one I am trying to create now.

The query I have posted grabs rows from all 3 tables from the last 10 hours and SUM the totals of Water, Electric, Natural Gas and Solar Generation. Now this only lets me display the result in 1 row. What I NEED to do is display those 10 hours, like you see in the screenshot.

My Code: https://www.screencast.com/t/SHTM7ERh

How I need it to display, but with the SUM function: https://www.screencast.com/t/aH07ZUvyG

```
SELECT
  timestamp AS Timestamp,
  SUM (water) AS 'Water Total',
  SUM (electric) AS 'Electric Total',
  SUM (naturalgas) AS 'N. Gas Total',
  SUM (solargeneration) AS 'Solar Total'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      timestamp,
      water,
      electric,
      naturalgas,
      solargeneration
    FROM
      wpdatatable_24
    UNION
    SELECT
      timestamp,
      water,
      electric,
      naturalgas,
      solargeneration
    FROM
      wpdatatable_23_1 
    UNION
    SELECT
      timestamp,
      water,
      electric,
      naturalgas,
      solargeneration
    FROM
      wpdatatable_23_1_1)  t
    WHERE   timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 HOUR;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Group GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp).
You should also decide to write SELECT min(timestamp) AS Timestamp, instead of SELECT timestamp AS Timestamp,

Comment: If that wasn't a big red easy button, I don't know what is LOL I appreciate you!